# Binary stream or something like this to save class like std::vector to a file?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm not good in IOstream library since I have accustom to stdio and stuff life this, however I got a problem I hoped to be solved in IOstream but I find that it probably not. So I'm quite new to standard C++ libraries but quite well with C++ OOP/Classes and so on.

So I can't use code like

```
printf (stream, "...", C);
```

if C is of an aggregate type because I can't create new format string options like %mytupe. Also I can't expect proper behavior of

```
fwrite/fread (&C, sizeof(C), 1, stream)
```

if T contains fields that are pointers because fwrite/fread will save/load value of a pointer but not a value stored in memory where the pointer refers to:

```
class MyClass
   {...
    private:
       {typename} Tp* Data;
   } C;
```

I don't care much of first limit because I can write a function that convert object of each of my class to a text string, it works even if but the last can't be solved easily. For example, I tried to create a function that save each class to binary file but I got a lot of problems with staff like luck of partial specialization of a template and so on (mo matter).

Being tired of making bugs and mistakes while rewriting standard code (like own string and file holder classes) I hoped that learning (at last!) of standard (written by clever people and well-tested :) library will help me  since I read a lot that standard C++ library solve first issue with using of streams. I can overload operator << and operator >> or so on to be sure that my class will be saved to or read from text file properly. But what about binary files which is much much more important for me?

What should I do if I want to save an object of class like vector, for example, to the binary file? Using of << and >> fails at all since it says that vector has no operators << and >> overloaded, but even if it had it would produce text data.

Staff like

```
vector <MyClass> V;
...
ofstream file ("file.bin", ios::binary);

int size1 = ;
file.write((const char*)&V.size(), sizeof(V.size()));
file.write((const char*)&V[0], V.size() * sizeof(MyClass));
```

is not suitable (and doesn't differs much from using of fwrite) since it saves value (address) of pointer field but not the data stored there (also, what if I declare a "two-dimension" vector as vector  > ??). So, if there was overloading of vector operator << like

```
template <class T> vector
  {public:
   ...    
     ostream operator << () const
        {ostream s;
         for (uint32_t k = 0; k < size(); k++)
            s << s << this->operator[] (k);
         return s;
        }
   private:
      T* Data;
  };
```

and if each T::operator << was overloaded too in the same way (for MyClass - to provide stream of data stored in MyCLass::Tp) it was saved.

(I know, I know, there should be iterator, but maybe I made a more serious mistake because of total misunderstanding of streams? Anyway just I'm talking about idea.)

Well, it is a way to convert data to text, not to got binary data as it is stored in memory, but I know there can be written an interface to work with binary data in the same way (maybe not using << and >> but function names, but it can be for sure)! The questing is: was it done in standard C++ library or somewhere else (another opensource library for C++)? Yes, yes, to properly write a vector to file in one line. (I'll be very surprised if it is not included into standard C++ because how do people save data they work to files if they want to use multidimension dynamic arrays?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the term "serialization", and you might want to use the [Boost::Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/) library for that purpose.

Comment: Well, third-party library as I afraid. Haven't learned standard library yet and need to learn another... Is std really lack of such an important feature? Do most of people use boost to save data?

Comment: So, I've looked how Serialization works and probably it can do everything I need, however binary archive is a thing that wasn't documented and recommended. But surprisingly file of saved binary archive not only contains some extra bytes (hope it its amount doesn't depend much from amount of effective data), but also includes 'human-readable' "hello" from boost aka text  'serialization::archive' in the beginning of binary file. Lol I'm kinda of being confused that everyone will see I used boost.

Comment: @Nick: "binary" data has so many variations that it's hard to  standardize. The C++ standard doesn't try. Boost is reasonably common, but for JPEG binary data you'd use a JPEG-specific library for instance.

Comment: Oh... I found multi_dimension array in boost and was so happy that it is the thing I need to very very much. And what? Boost doesn't provide serialization for it? How ironic! I'm totally depressed.

Comment: @MSalters, in case we don't use Boost, do you have any clue why does the following line won't work? `file.write((const char*)&V, V.size() * sizeof(MyClass));` Note that instead of using `(const char*)&V[0]` I considered `(const char*)&V`.

Comment: @Javier: simple: `(const char*)&V[0]` is possibly correct, `(const char*)&V` certainly isn't.

Comment: @MSalters, why it isn't correct? The `write` function requires as first parameter, the address of the block data that is going to be written, right? If we use `&V` aren't we obtaining the required address? Why do we need to get the address of the first element as `&V[0]`, does `&V` doesn't point to the beginning of the block of data `V`?

Comment: @Javier: No. `&V` is the address of the vector. `&V[0]` is the address of the first element of the vector. They're unrelated. The first is wherever the user put the vector; the second is allocated by `std::allocator`. The first doesn't change with a `.resize()`, the second might.